# returning a json encode on an api layer i'm getting the following errors

Tags: php, json, api

**api layer** (move_shopping_list.php):

```
    if (!isset($_GET['i_sign_in_token'])){
    die(json_encode('Must pass in the i_sign_in_token into the url'));
}

if (!isset($_GET['itm_cd'])){
    die(json_encode('Must pass in itm_cd into the URL'));
}

if (!isset($_GET['list_id_old']) || !isset($_GET['list_id_new'])){
    die(json_encode('Must pass in the list_id_old or new value into the URL'));
}


$list = new ShoppingListItem($_GET['i_sign_in_token'], $_GET['itm_cd'], $_GET['list_id_old'], $_GET['list_id_new']);
$moveItems = $item->move_between_lists($token, $_GET['itm_cd'], $_GET['list_id_old'], $_GET['list_id_new']);

echo json_encode($moveItems);
```

**Here is my move between lists method inside of my ShoppingListItem class**:

```
    public function move_between_lists($shopper, $new_list_id) {
    global $pd, $db;

    // todo: don't forget to update $this->ShoppingList
    $vars = array();
    $vars[] = array('i_sign_in_token', $shopper);
    $vars[] = array('itm_cd', $this->ITM_CD);
    $vars[] = array('list_id_old', $this->SHOPPING_LIST_ID);
    $vars[] = array('list_id_new', $new_list_id);

    $rows = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopping_list.Move_Bewteen_Lists(:i_sign_in_token, :itm_cd, :list_id_old, :list_id_new)', $vars);

    if ($rows == 'Y') {
        // Must have worked or it would have returned. 
        $this->SHOPPING_LIST_ID = $new_list_id;

        return true;
    } else { 
        return false;
    }


}
```

I keep getting these errors and i have no idea why.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Notice: Undefined index: i_sign_in_token in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 3 Notice: Undefined index: itm_cd in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 7 Notice: Undefined index: list_id_old in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined index: list_id_new in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 15 Notice: Undefined index: i_sign_in_token in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 19 Notice: Undefined index: itm_cd in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 19 Notice: Undefined index: list_id_old in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 19 Notice: Undefined index: list_id_new in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 19 Notice: Undefined variable: item in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 20 Fatal error: Call to a member function move_between_lists() on a non-object in /var/www/api/move_shopping_list.php on line 20`

Answer (score 2):

If the array key in $_GET is not set, you are explicitly checking whether or not this nonexistant key is also not an empty string. The logic is wrong, you must not use `&&` (and) but `||` (or).

Comment: Thanks for your help, using or solved my problems. =] I will mark as the correct answer when time expires.

Comment: How should i determine if it's an old shopping list or a new one? I'll update my code..

Comment: now i'm returning this error `"Must pass in the list_id_old value into the URL"` but i have list_id_old=1 in the URL.

Comment: No, the error most likely is `"Must pass in the list_id_old or new value into the URL"`, and that is because BOTH parameters must be present. If the old OR the new is not set, it fails. And please do not use GET requests to do destructive work (i.e. change data on the server) via an API. Use POST - that's what it is meant to do.